# Routing from outside of a Route component

Tags: react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have an app where i'm using react router and I can't figure out how to change the route in this use case. Here's how my code is structured:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
    <Panels />
    <Route path="/view" render={()=> <MyComponent />} />
    <Route path="/about" render={()=> <MyOtherComponent />} />
</Router>
```

Inside `<Panels>` are some tabs I have that I would like to change the route.

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={}> 
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1" > 
       <Somecomponent /> 
    </TabPane> 
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2"> 
      Test me 
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
```

These are antd tabs so they don't have a clickable component that I can put a `<Link>` into, and `<Panels>` is outside of a `<Route>` so I'm not sure if I'm able to access history object otherwise. I could put the panels in each `<Route>` but that would be really bad.

What way should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out finally.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={(key)=> this.props.history.push(`/${key}`)}> 
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1" > 
       <Somecomponent /> 
    </TabPane> 
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2"> 
      Test me 
    </TabPane>
</Tabs> 
...
export default withRouter(Panels);
```

wrapping the export with `withRouter` give the component access to the history object to push and read routes. I saw this solution initially but couldn't get it to work. Turns out it was because I was importing `withRouter` from `react-router` and not `react-router-dom`, so I was loading in the wrong history.